# how do i get height, width, perimeter and area of ​a binary image?

Tags: python, opencv

how do i get height, width, perimeter and area of ​​a binary image? I'm using the mask rcnn and opencv, i need a command that can extract, I have this command but I don't understand:

```
dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(train_files), channels,
                            image_height, image_width),
                     dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: I assume you want the height, width, perimeter and area of the white features in your binary image. To do that, use cv2.findContours() and then for each external contour use cv2.contourArea() for area  and cv2.arcLength() for perimeter from the docs at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/

Comment: _I have this command but I don't understand_ What don't you understand? Have you checked the documentation? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

The height and width are the pixel-unit dimensions of the image.  These are file characteristics available from the OS.  Bring up a directory listing in "icon" mode and hover your cursor over the file; in most graphic OS interfaces, the file info will pop up then.

Why do you need perimeter and area?  In pixel terms, they're the trivial equations we all had in school; in physical terms, they depend on the characteristics of the display device.  For the latter, you'd simply convert pixels to inches or centimetres, and then apply the same trivial equations.

```
perimeter = 2 * (length + width)
area = length * width
```